# How many 4 digit numbers can be formed such that they contain the digit 1 twice?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> How many $4$ digit numbers can be formed such that they contain the digit $1$ twice ?

My try as follows:

Choose  $2$ places out of $4$  for the $2$ ones in $4C2$

Choose  $2$ digits  out of $9$  for the  other  $2$  places in $9C2$

Permute the "3-digits" ($2$ ones as one digit , and the other $2$ digits)  in $3!$

The answer = $4C2 × 9C2×3!$=$1296$

Is my answer right?

Comment: It depends on whether 0112 is a valid 4 digit number.

Comment: @Glorfindel  absolutely  invalid ; but how can i  remove  such cases?

Comment: No, that's not the way to go. You could have guessed that the answer is wrong: there are 10000 (or 9000, depending on the definition) possible 4 digit numbers; 1296 is more than 10% of that, which is way too high.

Comment: @Glorfindel  so what is right way to  go?

Comment: Sorry, too busy right now to write a detailed answer. I'm sure somebody else will do it.

Comment: It is much easier to count how many 4digit numbers contain at most one $1$. Those having no $1$s: $8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$. Those having exactly one $1$ as the first digit: $9^3$. Those having exactly one $1$ not the first digit: $3 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$. So the final answer is $$9000 - (8 \cdot 9^3+9^3+24 \cdot 9^2) = 495$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at it this way:
the number can start in 2 ways- with a 1 or with other 8 digits ( 0 doesnt count)
So for 1 as first:

1*1*9*9+
1*9*1*9+
1*9*9*1
=243

for 8 possible digits as first:
8*1*1*9+
8*1*9*1+
8*9*1*1
=216

add these two options and you get 243+216 =459

Comment: Also this solution does not count numbers that have the digit "1" once three times and four times.

Comment: Elegant Solution,  thank you very much